# Simple if statement not working [nested php tags]

Tags: php, magento, if-statement, syntax

Here is the code below I am trying to say if that block is equal or less than 1000px height show the logo else the texting text. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Please remember this is inside magento is there a better way to write this I think with jquery right?

```
 <?php if (css class >= height of 62px): 
 echo '<h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong>
 <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" <?php echo MAGE::helper('ThemeOptions/Retina')->getRetinaData('logo'); ?> alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>';
         else: echo '<p> Testing </p>'; 
         endif; ?>
```

Comment: nested `<?php` tag does not work

Comment: ok now please help explain

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward comment. Learn to see code, it has structure. It is formulated in a particular way depending on where it is used.

Nested PHP tags don't work

```
<?php if :
  <?php ... ?>
?>
```

For php scripting where php code is predominant and the html is being generated as echo statements, this is the structure:

```
<?php

if (css class >= height of 62px) {
    echo '<h1 class="logo"><strong>' . $this->getLogoAlt() . '</strong>';
    echo '<a href="' . $this->getUrl('') . '" title="' . $this->getLogoAlt() . '" class="logo">';
    echo '<img src="' . $this->getLogoSrc() . '" ' . MAGE::helper('ThemeOptions/Retina')->getRetinaData('logo') . '" alt="' . $this->getLogoAlt() . '" />';
    echo '</a></h1>';
} else {
    echo '<p> Testing </p>'; 
}

?>
```

For html scripting where html tags are predominant and the PHP code is included as tags within html, this is the structure:

```
<?php if (css class >= height of 62px): ?>
   <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong>
   <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" 
   <?php echo MAGE::helper('ThemeOptions/Retina')->getRetinaData('logo') ?> alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
<?php else: ?>
   <p> Testing </p> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

**NOTE:** That `if` test and a couple other things in this code kind of render it to be pseudocode, probably not actually usable working Magento php. More work needs to be done with it.